# Creating a java API from a java class

Tags: api, jsp, get, response

I have a class of following format:

```
public class Process extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException,IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doPost(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException,IOException {
 if ((request.getParameter("choice")==null)&&(request.getParameter("term")!=null)){
   Bean b=new Bean(request.getParameter("term"));
  request.setAttribute("bean", b);
  request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp").forward(request, response);
  }
  //....many other if checks to dispatch the request to appropriate jsp pages
 }}
```

Now I want to convert this class into an API.I want to retain the functionality of it dispatching to appropriate pages, as thats how it functions for my application.But I want to be able to provide external access so that others can also make use of my application.
Right now this can be accessed by http://mytest.com/Process?term=test, and once i access it like that it forwards the response to result.jsp. The response is basically my other class(Bean) object and result.jsp uses the object to call its various get methods to retrieve data.

For this to be available externally I am thinking of introducing another parameter in URL, so that from external page people can send a request on http://mytest.com/Process?term=test&request=api and then I can check parameter to identify if its from external place, but i dunno how to send back response to the external client and if its a good idea to send the object to the client, since I don't think they will have access to class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Now I want to convert this class into an API*

In other words, you want to offer it as a webservice?

---

> *but I do not know how to send back response to the external client and if its a good idea to send the object to the client, since I don't think they will have access to class.*

Just return it in a common, fixed and prespecified format. For example, [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) or even [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

JSON, with help of [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
Bean bean = createItSomehow();

response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

Gson gson = new Gson();
response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(bean));
```

XML, with help of [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/):

```
Bean bean = createItSomehow();

response.setContentType("text/xml");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bean.class);  
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();  
marshaller.marshal(bean, response.getOutputStream());
```

The Java EE API offers the [JAX-WS](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html) and [JAX-RS](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html) API's for exactly this purpose which removes the need of fiddling with low level Servlet API boilerplate to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following library . http://www.jboss.org/resteasy . It's quite easy to set it up and start using .
   You can have a rest ful api wrapper on top of your current implementation with this library .
Let me know if thats what you wanted to do ?